# jQuery popeye resize full image

Tags: jquery

I am using [JQuery popeye 2.1](http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/demo.html) for my current project. Here my problem is full image takes its own size, it looks bad for large size image. I want to resize/scale them.

After inspect their code I found that they are using image as a div background image, so if I resize the div it didn't resize the image. I also try [this](http://jquerypopeye.uservoice.com/forums/49985-general/suggestions/718758-resize-full-image-if-bigger-than-the-window) post, it didn't worked out (It is for version 2.0.4).

My current solution is save an extra image (resized/scaled) for full size image, which is working fine.

But I am looking for something like resize/scale image on client side (ex- use maxWidth, minWidth).

browser support:

- IE 8 and 8+
- and other standard browser

Please help.

Comment: reduce height width .

Comment: Pratik Joshi: I can't get your point, please clarify